If an element exist in a list, ignore other similar elements in c#
I have got a string list with generated programmatically like this:
var list = new List<string>
{
    "anonim",
    "anonim şirket",
    "anonim şirketler",
    "tapu",
    "tapu senedi",
    "tapu kütüğü",
    "yaptırım",
    "müeyyide",
    "işçi",
    "işçi alacakları",
    "işçi hakları",
    "işçi lehine yorum ilkesi",
    "işçilik sözleşmesi",
    "limited şirket",
    "sınırlı ayni hak",
    "telif hakkı",
    "unutulma hakkı",
    "yolsuz tescil",
    "zamanaşımı"
};

It contains many repeated similar elements. So I thinked that ignore these with the help of dictinary. If dictionary key exists in the list, I want to ignore elements separated by commas in the dictionary value. Here is the dictionary:
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"anonim şirket", "anonim, anonim şirketler"}, 
    {"tapu senedi", "tapu, tapu kütüğü"}, 
    {"yaptırım", "müeyyide"}, 
    {"işçi hakları", "işçi, işçi alacakları, işçi lehine yorum ilkesi, işçilik sözleşmesi"}
};

So the final list I want to get is as follows:
var new_list = new List<string>()
{
    "anonim şirket",
    "tapu senedi",
    "yaptırım",
    "işçi hakları",
    "limited şirket",
    "sınırlı ayni hak",
    "telif hakkı",
    "unutulma hakkı",
    "yolsuz tescil",
    "zamanaşımı"
};

I don't know how to do this. I thought of writing a foreach loop like below. But I don't know what to write in foreach loop.
var newList = new List<string>();
foreach (var l in list)
{
    // WHAT MUST I DO IN HERE?
}


You need to define your intent here better. For example, why {"tapu senedi", "tapu, tapu kütüğü"} and not {"tapu", "tapu senedi"} - both are in your first list. Where do you get these values, etc. What is the threshold of dismissing a value and so on?

@T.S. - These values come in a form of list. The list is also from a database. Since I was working on the list, I did not want to bother you masters with the database. As for why some items... I'm a jurist by profession. Software is a hobby that makes my work much easier. So the more legally correct ones are the ones I gave in the dictionary key.

Storing the duplicates as comma-separated strings in a Dictionary<string, string>, is going to be neither pretty nor efficient. Instead of presenting to us your attempted solution to the problem and ask us to fix your solution, it is preferable to describe the problem as better as you can, and let us suggest a solution. Chances are that you'll get better help this way.

Let's say that the list contains the values "anonim" and "anonim şirketler", and doesn't contain the value "anonim şirket". What should happen in that case? Should one of the two similar values be removed, or both should stay in the list? If one should be removed, which one?

@TheodorZoulias - I appreciate you trying to help me. But the list is really like the example I gave. So the list contains both anonim, anonim şirket and anonim şirketler.

Btw no offence to your preferred alphabet, but it's more likely to receive help here if your example dataset is composed from English words. Most people here are more familiar with the English language and the Latin alphabet, and will be easier for them to spot visually the strings that are similar from the strings that are not. The easier you make it for us to help you, the more likely to get helped.

If the program input and output is static, do not write a program. If input can change, you should be able to explain the expected behavior for a different set of data. Question: with list and dict, which is dynamic input, which is static supporting data and/or intermediate results (processed from input)?

If the list is already known, have you considered curating it by hand, and storing the curated list in some other database table? It should be more straightforward and less error-prone than trying to deduplicate a known list programmatically.

For you software is a hobby, for us is serious business. You must help us to understand your problem, your input, output and criteria. Even AI will not be able to solve it without common algorithm. for example, AI can find a white square shape in the camera image, etc.
Non of your comments have helped us to come closer to suggestion. For example, if you have "anonim", "anonim şirket", "anonim şirketler", - how do you decide, which to keep and which is duplicate and discard?

@TheodorZoulias Wasn't it clear that if the list contained a key in the dictionary, that the items in that key's value should be removed? That's how I understood it, and what the expected results show.

@T.S. He specified that, if a key is present in the list, the items in the associated value should be removed from the list. That is a very straight-forward algorithm.

@RufusL yes, it's quite clear. It's just not a problem general enough to worth solving, because the list is already known. The OP can't specify what the output should be for a slightly different input, which is quite disappointing. Personally I would be willing to try solving a more general problem, but not this one.

@RufusL "if the list contained a key in the dictionary, that the items in that key's value should be removed" -- I would suggest to include this clarification in the question (if you are 100% confident that it describes the algorithm that the OP wants to implement).

@TheodorZoulias He did include that in the question: "If dictionary key exists in the list, I want to ignore elements separated by commas in the dictionary value."

@RufusL ah, yes, you are right.

A simple way to do this (but not the most efficient) would be to:

make a copy of the original list
loop through the keys of the dictionary
if a key exists in the new list, remove the items specified in the value from the new list.

We can split the value on the comma character to create a mini-list to iterate over for removal of items (note that it would be easier if you used a Dictionary<string, List<string>> instead):
// Make a copy of the original list
var new_list = list.ToList();

// Loop through the dictionary
foreach (var item in dict)
{
    // If our new list contains a key
    if (new_list.Contains(item.Key))
    {
        // Loop through the values associated with 
        // that key and remove them from the list
        foreach(var value in item.Value.Split(',').Select(i => i.Trim()))
        {
            new_list.Remove(value);
        }
    }
}

// Display results
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", new_list));



EDIT:
A more efficient way would probably be to create a list of items to exclude first, by searching for the dictionary keys in the list as we did before, but collecting all the values in a separate list, and then we can use the Except method to remove the items (which has the added benefit [to some] of being done in one line):
var new_list = list.Except(dict
    .Where(item => list.Contains(item.Key))
    .SelectMany(item => item.Value.Split(',').Select(i => i.Trim())))
    .ToList(); // Call ToList() if you need a List and not just an IEnumerable


You have an O(n³) algorithm here. The List<T>.Remove is O(n), and you are calling  it in an inner loop.

@TheodorZoulias Yes, I called out right away that it wasn't efficient. Just giving a starting point for thinking about it.

Rufus the text in your answer gives the impression that the slow part is the "make a copy of the original list", not what follows afterwards.

Now it's nicer, but still it's not clear what is the source of the low efficiency, that should have to be improved in case the algorithm takes hours to complete.

@TheodorZoulias true. i added a more efficient method for doing it, but i think the original answer was enough for the question. the glimpse into the design itself leads me to believe that this is not the least efficient piece of code. :)

I am skeptical that the LINQ approach is an improvement (regarding performance). It doesn't take advantage from the dict being a dictionary.

@TheodorZoulias let me know if you come up with something better!

Most likely I won't. I don't find the question to be intriguing/challenging/interesting enough.
